# Haskell $ operator: why doesn't this work?

Tags: haskell

In the *Haskell Programming from First Principles* book there is an exercise which tells us to write a function which takes a string with spaces inside, splits it by the spaces, and loads the non-space chunks into a list of strings. My first try was:

```
splitString :: String -> [String]
splitString str
  | str == "" = []
  | otherwise = takeWhile (/=' ') str : splitString $ drop 1 $ dropWhile (/=' ') str
```

Now this doesn't compile. If I replace the first ($) (right after `splitString`) with the corresponding pair of parentheses instead like so:

```
takeWhile (/=' ') str : splitString (drop 1 $ dropWhile (/=' ') str)
```

then it works. Based on what I've learned so far about ($) though, shouldn't the two be equivalent? ($) is right associative, so it looks to me like what ought to be happening is

1. `dropWhile (/=' ') str` is evaluated first
2. `drop 1 (dropWhile (/=' ') str)` is next
3. then the result is passed onto `splitString`.

Instead, I get an error from `ghc` which says

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char] -> [String]’
            with actual type ‘[[Char]]’
The first argument of ($) takes one argument,
but its type ‘[[Char]]’ has none
```

I can see that by "first argument of ($)" it's talking about `splitString`, but I'm puzzled by what the statement

```
but its type `[[Char]]` has none
```

is supposed to mean.

Comment: You do know you are just implementing `words`, right?

Comment: @chepner: no... I didn't know that. I'm a total beginner to Haskell. I just want to know how it works.

Comment: Why the downvote? Everyone always explains the `$` operator as the same thing as parenthesizing, but it clearly isn't in this case. And I felt it was important to understand why.

Comment: `$` reduces the *need* for parenthesizing; anyone who actually says they are the *same* is being misleading at best. `f 3 + 5` is the same as `(f 3) + 5` because function application has a higher precedence than `+`. `f $ 3 + 5` is the same as `f (3 + 5)` because `$` has a *lower* precedence than `+`.

Comment: The downvoter (not me) presumably felt you could have looked up the definition of `($)`  yourself.

Comment: @chepner: thank you for that. the book I'm reading literally states "If you like, a way to understand ($) in words is: “evaluate everything to the right of me first."". I now understand that this isn't a complete picture. And I did look the definition up, but the fact that parenthesizing essentially loses the infix operator `$` and leaves an implicit function application was key. I didn't notice that immediately.

Comment: For what it's worth, I haven't been terribly impressed with that book. It's far too verbose. (In its defense, I read it long after I picked up most of the basics, so I definitely wasn't the target audience.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123107/discussion-between-gogurt-and-chepner).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code will work if you add parens as indicated below:

```
...
  | otherwise = takeWhile (/=' ') str : ( splitString $ drop 1 $ dropWhile (/=' ') str )
--                                     ^^^                                            ^^^
```

Otherwise Haskell is interpreting the otherwise clause as:

```
( takeWhile (/=' ') str : splitString )
    $ drop 1
    $ dropWhile (/= ' ') str
```

**Update**

The version you mention in the comments:

```
     takeWhile (/= ' ') str : splitString ( ... )
--   \__ a __/ \_ b _/   c  : \___ d ___/ \_ e _/
```

has the form `a b c : d e` which Haskell always interprets as `(a b c) : (d e)` since `:` is the only infix operator appearing the expression.

When you have something like:

```
    a b c : d e $ f $ g
```

you have to take into consideration the relative precedence of the `:` and `$` infix operators. Since `$` is [defined as `infixr 0`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:-36-), it doesn't
bind as tight as `:` and you get the following right-associative grouping:

```
    (a b c : d e) $ (f $ g)
```

Comment: But why is that? If I add parentheses like I suggested in my question, then shouldn't Haskell still try to group `splitString` to the block on the left? I still don't understand why one works and the other doesn't.

Comment: @gogurt The `(:)` operator has precedence 5, but `($)` has precedence 0, so `(:)` binds tighter than `($)`.

Comment: Right. But I was asking about the version written `takeWhile (/=' ') str : splitString (drop 1 $ dropWhile (/=' ') str)`. This works for some reason, even though I didn't explicitly group `splitString` to the right side of `:` as in ErikR's answer.

Comment: Answer updated. Indeed, a good approach to debugging problems like this with `$` is to replace `$` with explicit parens.

Comment: @ErikR: ah, I see. and Haskell interprets the statement like that because function application has higher precedence than any other operator. That gets to the heart of it. Thank you.